TabbedPage displays NavigationBar incorrectly
I'm developing an app in .NET MAUI, but when I show a TabbedPage in a NavigationPage, the appearance of my navigation bar is buggy only on Windows.
Display error:

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I tried to set the TabbedPage at the bottom, but I can't do this on Windows.

This is the design on the windows platform. You can check this document link Create a TabbedPage.
Regardless of the approach taken, the location of the tab bar in a TabbedPage is platform-dependent.On Windows, the list of tabs appears at the top of the screen, and the page content is below. Each tab consists of a title.

Thanks for the answer. I understand that the tab on Windows is designed for the top. But is it possible to set the navigationbar to full width?

It is the full width on the windows platform. You can populate a TabbedPage with a DataTemplate. Here is the document you can refer to.
